Multiple Walkthroughable Elements in a Single `CopilotStep`
I have a use case where I need to include multiple walkthroughable elements inside a single CopilotStep. Specifically, I have a View containing three Text components. I would like to make two of these Text components walkthroughable using const CopilotText = walkthroughable(Text);, while the third Text remains non-walkthroughable.
Here’s a simplified example of what I’m trying to achieve:
import { walkthroughable } from 'react-native-copilot';

const CopilotText = walkthroughable(Text);

<CopilotStep text="Step 1" order={1} name="step1">
  <View>
    <CopilotText>Walkthrough Text 1</CopilotText>
    <Text>Non-Walkthrough Text</Text>
    <CopilotText>Walkthrough Text 2</CopilotText>
  </View>
</CopilotStep>

Currently, it seems that the library does not support multiple walkthroughable elements within the same CopilotStep. Is there a way to achieve this with the current API? Or would this require an enhancement to the library?
